# Python - Ttk Treeview - hide rows

Tags: python, treeview, row

I'm using a Ttk treeview to display a big amount of datas (i.e. 20 columns of 60.000 rows) from a csv file.

I added the possibility to filter a bit all these datas. For the columns, no problem as I'm using displaycolumn method but for the rows I couldn't find other solution than clear my treeview then add again the datas I want, but it's really  time consuming.

Do you know a way to hide a row in ttk treeview without clearing it ?
Maybe I'm not using the right widget to display these amount of datas, do you have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you *must* "detach" the items you want to hide from the tree, and later "reattach" them when you decide that you need to show them. More precisely, the docstring for `Treeview.detach` says:

> Unlinks all of the specified items from the tree.
>
> The items and all of their descendants are still present, and may
>   be reinserted at another point in the tree, but will not be
>   displayed. The root item may not be detached.

Another user explains how to use `reattach` in [this answer to another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47055786/284696).